# How to copy files from Mac OS to Windows which are in same network using command line?

Tags: windows, macos, command-line, terminal

I know that , we can copy files from host to another from mac using finder/smb protocol.

But I would like to copy files from mac to windows machine using command line. so that, I can call the same pro-grammatically.

Could anyone please guide?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can copy the files using the Finder then you have connected to the SMB share.  Usually, you can see this from the command line by looking in the `/Volumes` folder; if it doesn't look like it's there, try running the `mount` command to see other places things might be connected.  The following assumes the SMB is mounted in `/Volumes`, adjust as necessary for your particular case.

On the command line, issue the command:

```
ls /Volumes
```

You should see the SMB share listed along with some other names.

Then to copy files to it:

```
cp myfiles/* /Volumes/MySMBShare/mydirectory
```

If the name of the share has spaces in it you will need to escape them with backslashes like so:

```
cp myfiles/* /Volumes/My\ SMB\ Share/mydirectory
```

Comment: great! but how to make sure that this host is always connected to mac ; is there any setting? I saw many times that finder few timeout asks for connectivity to same host. ** just want to make sure that script doesnt get halt at any stage **

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Perhaps my company have linked to the SMB folder in some other way but I get nothing but "Macintosh HD" in /Volumes

Comment: Just after posting that, I found that if you type `mount` then you see where the SMB location is mounted. In my case, in my user directory.

Comment: I'm on macOS Catalina, and even though I have access to an SMB share, I don't see anything under `~/Volumes`